# How can I add text above a horizontal line?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, overleaf

I am trying to produce a LaTeX document with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor} % For \textcolor
\makeatletter % For \@height and \@z@
\begin{document}
{\Large Hello}
\textcolor{blue}{\textit{World!}} \leaders\hrule\@height1.0pt\hfill\kern\z@
\end{document}
```

This produces a document where the horizontal line is not under "World!" as I would like. Instead, the horizontal line appears next to it.

[image]

I would like to adjust the settings so that the horizontal line appears under the text "World!", as shown in the following diagram:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Like this? `{\Large Hello} \rlap{\textcolor{blue}{\textit{World!}}} \leaders\hrule\@height1.0pt\hfill\kern\z@`. By the way, this is not the best solution.

Comment: @Sigur This is the answer I was looking for, thank you.